# Unity - Missing Render Setting from Edit menu

Tags: unity

Where I can select Render Setting from Edit menu from Unity5? It looks missing.

[image]

It suppose to be like this one.

[image]

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Window>Lighting from the menubar.

That should have all of the same settings as render settings in Unity 4.